# Can you provide a login screen for Actions on Google

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We currently have an Alexa app that lets users ask for details about upcoming events, now the company wants to implement the same thing for Google's assistant. It seems like this is supported through "Actions On Google", which is  very similar to Alexa.

One thing Alexa allowed us to do that I cant figure out with Google is setup a login screen. When a user first accessed the app via voice command, it would take them to an authentication page. We used this to tie an Amazon user to our internal records so that we could identify their specific information when they made a request. It was also used for authentication and authorization.

I dont see how to do that with Google. I assume that you can, but I havent been able to find it. Is there a way to set up a login screen so that when someone says "Hey (Agent), tell me about my day tomorrow", I can confirm who the person is to look up their information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you're looking for [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking).

The term comes from linking the account they log into with your service to the account that Google uses to track them. You'll need to implement a basic OAuth server, including the page where they log into your service when they're directed there from the Assistant, and a way to issue authentication tokens to the Assistant. When requests come in from a user with a linked account, you'll get the tokens from the user, and you can use this to identify who the request came from.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Ill give you credit in 7 minutes =)